# In PHP how do you do an if statement within the if of an if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

So the question is confusing I know. This is what I am wondering how to do.

I have the following if statement:

```
if(
    (isset($_POST['billing_company']) && $_POST['billing_company'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['billing_address']) && $_POST['billing_address'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['billing_city']) && $_POST['billing_city'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['billing_state']) && $_POST['billing_state'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['billing_zip']) && $_POST['billing_zip'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['billing_phone']) && $_POST['billing_phone'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['location_name']) && $_POST['location_name'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['location_address']) && $_POST['location_address'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['location_city']) && $_POST['location_city'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['location_state']) && $_POST['location_state'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['location_zip']) && $_POST['location_zip'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['location_phone']) && $_POST['location_phone'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_firstname']) && $_POST['user_firstname'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_lastname']) && $_POST['user_lastname'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_username']) && $_POST['user_username'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_email']) && $_POST['user_email'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_password']) && $_POST['user_password'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_mobile']) && $_POST['user_mobile'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['payment_cc_name']) && $_POST['payment_cc_name'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['payment_cc_number']) && $_POST['payment_cc_number'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['payment_cc_expo_month']) && $_POST['payment_cc_expo_month'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['payment_cc_expo_year']) && $_POST['payment_cc_expo_year'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['payment_cc_code']) && $_POST['payment_cc_code'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['terms']) && $_POST['terms'] != "")
){
```

However, based on some variables, I may no longer need any of the billing information. So I am wondering if I can do an IF inside the IF, so something like this:

```
if(
    ($billingRequired == 1){
        (isset($_POST['billing_company']) && $_POST['billing_company'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['billing_address']) && $_POST['billing_address'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['billing_city']) && $_POST['billing_city'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['billing_state']) && $_POST['billing_state'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['billing_zip']) && $_POST['billing_zip'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['billing_phone']) && $_POST['billing_phone'] != "") && 
    }
    (isset($_POST['location_name']) && $_POST['location_name'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['location_address']) && $_POST['location_address'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['location_city']) && $_POST['location_city'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['location_state']) && $_POST['location_state'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['location_zip']) && $_POST['location_zip'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['location_phone']) && $_POST['location_phone'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_firstname']) && $_POST['user_firstname'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_lastname']) && $_POST['user_lastname'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_username']) && $_POST['user_username'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_email']) && $_POST['user_email'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_password']) && $_POST['user_password'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['user_mobile']) && $_POST['user_mobile'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['payment_cc_name']) && $_POST['payment_cc_name'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['payment_cc_number']) && $_POST['payment_cc_number'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['payment_cc_expo_month']) && $_POST['payment_cc_expo_month'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['payment_cc_expo_year']) && $_POST['payment_cc_expo_year'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['payment_cc_code']) && $_POST['payment_cc_code'] != "") && 
    (isset($_POST['terms']) && $_POST['terms'] != "")
){
```

I'm pretty sure there isn't but wanted to check with people smarter than me. I know I can do some nesting in side the `{}` but wanted to not have to check each variable inside a very deep nest.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you actually tried it to see what happens?

Comment: Yes. The page doesn't render due to an error.

Comment: I take it you don't have error reporting on then?

Comment: I have it enabled with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1')` but Chrome just shows a 500 error.

Comment: Also, instead of using `isset()` and `!=""` on the same variable, If it will not be 0, just use `!empty()`.

Comment: This certainly is an syntax error: `&& }`

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the error. I blurred the domain, as I don't want my url in the wild: http://imgur.com/FnIz2w1

Comment: @arkascha yes, I removed the trailing `&&` and still same result.

Comment: @rvirelli dont just remove something... Why don't try to recreate it with if-else statements in if-else statements

Comment: @KoenHollander Yes. That is the plan. I was just wondering if what I was asking was possible. If not, I will restructure all my code to do progressive checks with if else.

Comment: Try to check every single field in a single if-statement and
don't forget to trim your data when you check if it is empty

Comment: @tvirelli Yes it is possible, it is really nice to do that and you can finally see where mistakes are made.

Comment: On a semi-related side note, when you get a 500 error you should check the error.log on the server for specific details on what the error is. In the vast majority of cases it will give you a file and line number and a reasonably good description of the error. If you don't have access to that log, you should speak to your host or server administrator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add () around the section you want to combine and it will resolve to a simple boolean which can be included in your if statement

The logic here reads "if (billing is not required or billing fields are all filled out) and all the non-billing fields are filled out, then..."

```
if(
    (($billingRequired != 1) || (
        (isset($_POST['billing_company']) && $_POST['billing_company'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['billing_address']) && $_POST['billing_address'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['billing_city']) && $_POST['billing_city'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['billing_state']) && $_POST['billing_state'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['billing_zip']) && $_POST['billing_zip'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['billing_phone']) && $_POST['billing_phone'] != "")
    ))
    &&
    (
        (isset($_POST['location_name']) && $_POST['location_name'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['location_address']) && $_POST['location_address'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['location_city']) && $_POST['location_city'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['location_state']) && $_POST['location_state'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['location_zip']) && $_POST['location_zip'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['location_phone']) && $_POST['location_phone'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['user_firstname']) && $_POST['user_firstname'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['user_lastname']) && $_POST['user_lastname'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['user_username']) && $_POST['user_username'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['user_email']) && $_POST['user_email'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['user_password']) && $_POST['user_password'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['user_mobile']) && $_POST['user_mobile'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['payment_cc_name']) && $_POST['payment_cc_name'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['payment_cc_number']) && $_POST['payment_cc_number'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['payment_cc_expo_month']) && $_POST['payment_cc_expo_month'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['payment_cc_expo_year']) && $_POST['payment_cc_expo_year'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['payment_cc_code']) && $_POST['payment_cc_code'] != "") && 
        (isset($_POST['terms']) && $_POST['terms'] != "")
    )
{
    //statements
}
```

Although I suspect this could be done better within a loop, maybe it's personal preference, but I'd be happier with something like this

```
$billingRequiredFields = array('billing_company','billing_address','billing_city','billing_state','billing_zip','billing_phone','location_name','location_address','location_city','location_state','location_zip','location_phone','user_firstname','user_lastname','user_username','user_email','user_password','user_mobile','payment_cc_name','payment_cc_number','payment_cc_expo_month','payment_cc_expo_year','payment_cc_code','terms');
$billingNotRequiredFields = array('location_name','location_address','location_city','location_state','location_zip','location_phone','user_firstname','user_lastname','user_username','user_email','user_password','user_mobile','payment_cc_name','payment_cc_number','payment_cc_expo_month','payment_cc_expo_year','payment_cc_code','terms')
$requiredFields = ($billingRequired == 1) ? $billingRequiredFields : $billingNotRequiredFields;
$continue = true;
foreach($requiredFields as $field) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || $_POST[$field] == '') {
        $continue = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($continue) {
    // statements
}
```

Comment: You should add brackets around the two `$billingRequired` evaluating terms for better readability.

Comment: That worked. I had to remove the trailing `&&` after `billing_phone`, but it worked. Thanks! At @KoenHollander horror, I am going to accept this answer, not because it is best practices, but because it answers the original question I asked.

Comment: I also added an alternative that may be of interest to you, and yes, @arkashca that may help if the OP finds it easier to read, I'll add those into the code to make it clearer

Comment: if `$billingRequired` equals one, then shouldn't the other fields still be checked? i.e. location_name, location_address, etc.

Comment: @Andrew you could very well be right, I didn't look at the logic of the decisions that are being made, I just answered his syntax issue. The logic of the code I posted is the same as the intention behind the code he posted in the question. If it's wrong, then that's a different question

Comment: I think the way that the OP structured his pseudo code, he/she meant that the billing stuff should be validated *in addition* to the other fields if billingRequired=1. Is that right @tvirelli ?

Comment: Ooh I see what you mean, yes, that was actually a mistake on my part. I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @tvirelli following Andrew's comment, I have edited the code, do you understand what I have changed? I can explain further if necessary

Comment: yes, the new way that @DarrenH added is very close to the suggestion by NativeCoder. The new example is perfect.

Comment: @DarrenH, the one thing I like better about Native Coder's example is the merge. That way I don't have to double up on arrays. There will always be required fields, but sometimes there my be required billing. His example allows be to create even more arrays and only merge them if need be.

Answer (score 2):

better yet, don't put so many tests in the primary conditional, just make a function to test it, and then test for === true or === false

```
function validate_input($billingRequired=0){
    $b_valid = true;
    if( $billingRequired == 1 ){
         if (!isset($_POST['billing_company']) || $_POST['billing_company'] == ""){
            $b_valid = false;
         }
         elseif (!isset($_POST['billing_address']) || $_POST['billing_address'] == ""){
            $b_valid = false;
         }
         elseif (!isset($_POST['billing_city']) || $_POST['billing_city'] == ""){
            $b_valid = false;
         }
         elseif (!isset($_POST['billing_state']) || $_POST['billing_state'] == ""){
            $b_valid = false;
         }
         elseif (!isset($_POST['billing_zip']) || $_POST['billing_zip'] == ""){
            $b_valid = false;
         }
         elseif (!isset($_POST['billing_phone']) || $_POST['billing_phone'] == ""){
            $b_valid = false;
         }
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['location_name']) || $_POST['location_name'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['location_address']) || $_POST['location_address'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['location_city']) || $_POST['location_city'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['location_state']) || $_POST['location_state'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['location_zip']) || $_POST['location_zip'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['location_phone']) || $_POST['location_phone'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['user_firstname']) || $_POST['user_firstname'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['user_lastname']) || $_POST['user_lastname'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['user_username']) || $_POST['user_username'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['user_email']) || $_POST['user_email'] != "") == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif  (!isset($_POST['user_password']) || $_POST['user_password'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['user_mobile']) || $_POST['user_mobile'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['payment_cc_name']) || $_POST['payment_cc_name'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['payment_cc_number']) || $_POST['payment_cc_number'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['payment_cc_expo_month']) || $_POST['payment_cc_expo_month'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['payment_cc_expo_year']) || $_POST['payment_cc_expo_year'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['payment_cc_code']) || $_POST['payment_cc_code'] == ""){
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    elseif (!isset($_POST['terms']) || $_POST['terms'] == "")
        $b_valid = false;
    }
    return $b_valid;
}
```

now it's easy to modify / read etc. Because empty can be slightly ambiguous I find myself avoiding it as a rule, despite  it's stylistic elegance.

To make this even cleaner, I'd probably write it like this:

```
function validate_input($billingRequired=0){
    $b_valid = true;
    $a_billing = array('billing_company','billing_address'...);
    $a_main = array('billing_address','location_address'...);
    if( $billingRequired == 1 ){
         $a_main = array_merge($a_billing,$a_main);
    }
    foreach ($a_main as $test){
       if (!isset($_POST[$test]) || trim($_POST[$test]) == "")
            $b_valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $b_valid;
}
```

With the caveat that assumes empty values are "", which wouldn't generally be the case for select lists etc.

Comment: this is by far the BEST option as to how to handle this and I will end up using this idea in my actual code! I already accepted the other answer for the simple fact that it answered my question of "Is this possible". I will up vote!

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is create an array at the top of the script that contains a list of all the POSTed variables that are required, then I would just loop through them. Your code would be way smaller. and almost as concise....

```
//We NEED these fields for the script to work...
$requiredFields = array(
    "fname",
    "lname",
    "phone",
    "accredited",
    "etc, etc"
);

//IF you require billing, 
if($billingRequired){
    // Define the billing fields that we expect to be POSTed...
    $billingFields  = array(
        "billing_compnay",
        "billing_address",
        "etc, etc"
    );
    // Add the billing fields to the required fields
    $requiredFields = array_merge($requiredFields, $billingFileds);
}

// Loop through required fields and check to see if they are all POSTed
foreach($requiredFields as $fieldName){
    // IF a required field is not set...
    if(empty($_POST[$fieldName])){
        // Do stuff, call a function, show an error, etc.
        break; // Or redirect, or exit after a JSON response, whatever. Just be sure to end the loop here for efficiency.
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, okay, well really need to chill on response to people as they keep getting better, This is much less code to add new fields and allows much more freedom moving forward! Great code!

Comment: Thanks buddy. I use it in all of my scripts and it works great. Did you change the form? NO PROBLEM! just edit the array that's at the top of the script and BOOM. problem solved. :)

Comment: I like the idea of this merging the arrays, definitely an improvement on my version. Although my inner pedant disapproves of your misspelling of 'etc'

Comment: HAHAHAAH. I just wanted to keep the code short so you could get the idea of what I was doing. :) I'll fix it :)

Comment: lol, I was in the middle of posting this very suggestion as well when work called and I had to stop. Note that as I said in my updated post, looping it assumes that all form fields have an empty value of "" which is rarely the case. I'd also trim the values etc.